# How to add Widget layout updates field in my custom module admin form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, widget, widget-instance

I am working on a custom module where I want to add the following field in my admin form

in have my admin form developed in using ui_component I want to add this field (in this picture) after a field

```
<field name="slider_type">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">vendor\modulename\Model\Config\Source\ProductType</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">vendor_modulename/js/form/element/options</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Type</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">modulename</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">slider_type</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

[image]

how can I add this in my admin form please help

Comment: Show your code then easy to help.

Comment: i have updated you can check now... actually i have a admin form in ui_component i want to add this feild (the one placed in widiget) to my ui_component form

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function getWidgetInstance()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_vihadigitalcom_popup_items');
}
function _prepareform(){ 
 $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_vihadigitalcom_popup_items');
         $widgetInstance = $this->getWidgetInstance();

$layoutBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Magento\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Instance\Edit\Tab\Main\Layout::class
        )->setWidgetInstance(
            $widgetInstance
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('layout_updates_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Layout Updates')]);
        $fieldset->addField('layout_updates', 'note', []);
        $form->getElement('layout_updates_fieldset')->setRenderer($layoutBlock);
}
```